# XConnect IndexWorker error "Tokens are incompatible, they have different set of shards."

Tags: xconnect

The log for my IndexWorker is filling up with the following error:

> Tokens are incompatible, they have different set of shards

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Credit to [Rob Earlam](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/269/rob-earlam) for helping me find the solution to this.

Essentially, information about the shard databases is stored in the xdb index. If either the server or database name of your shards changes, this will result in this error being logged. In my case, we had cloned (what was now) "production" to be the new "UAT" but the index still referred to the production database server.

To confirm if this is indeed your problem, you can do the following (skip ahead if you're already sure):

In Solr, query the `Sitecore_xdb` index for `id:xdb-index-token`. Next, copy the `xdbtokenbytes_s` value and provide it to the following PowerShell script:

[ConvertFrom-XdbIndexToken.ps1](https://gist.github.com/richardszalay/93b7c03e7e92c26ffab09693750c9811)

```
param(
    [string]$Token = (Read-Host "Enter xdbtokenbytes_s value")
)

$bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($Token)
$ms = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
$bf = [System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter]::new()
$dict = $bf.Deserialize($ms);

Write-Output $dict
```

It will output something like this:

```
[DataSource=DBSERVERNAME Database=Sitecore_Xdb.Collection.Shard0] - 1739
[DataSource=DBSERVERNAME Database=Sitecore_Xdb.Collection.Shard1] - 1349
```

If the indexed values don't match the actual db Server/Database, you'll need to rebuild the XDB index. There is [documentation available on how to do this](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/rebuild-index/rebuild-solr-index.html), but it will usually boil down to running the following on your xconnect server:

```
XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -requestrebuild
```

**Original C# version**

If PowerShell isn't an option, here's the equivalent in C#. Run it in a console app (or via a service like [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "TOKEN_HERE";
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
        using (var rs = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))
        {
            var sf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            var o = sf.Deserialize(rs) as Dictionary<string, long?>;
            foreach(var kvp in o)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key} - {kvp.Value}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im getting the error but my DBSERVERNAME and Database names are correct. any advice?

Comment: @Richard I am also getting the same error. In my case, despite executing the command XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -requestrebuild, solr still points to old shard db server. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

In case this error persists, even after you rebuild the XDB index, you might as well want to check the items under `/sitecore/system/List Manager/ListOperations` node.

These items are created by the List Manager application and they contain a field named **Sync Token**. You should update the **Sync Token** field of each item with the one corresponding to your local instance. These items will eventually disappear as the List Manager process them.

To find out what Sync Token you should use, just do as [Richard Szalay](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/1173/richard-szalay) suggested above. In Solr, query the `[prefix]_xdb` index for `id:xdb-index-token` field.

Comment: I am also getting the same error. In my case, despite executing the command XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -requestrebuild, solr still points to old shard db server. For me the node /sitecore/system/List Manager/ListOperations is empty.  Any idea how to fix this?